# Where is the Clamp Node

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, node-editor, shaders, eevee-render-engine

I've been experimenting with nodes recently and following along with other people's work. I've noticed they used a clamp node that I cannot seem to find in the search menu.

This blender documents say it can be found under Converter>Clamp Node.
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/shader_nodes/converter/clamp.html

[image: Screenshot from Blender Docs]

[image: Converter Nodes]

I've tried experimenting with the Math node but couldn't get the same results. I'm using Blender 2.8

Is there a way to create the Clamp Node with Node Wrangler

Comment: This is with a diffrent node that is set to clamp it maybe mixrgb. You may want to download the file and see which one it is.

Answer (score 4):

The *Clamp* node is available in Blender 2.81

Comment: At the time of writing the beta version can be downloaded from the experimental builds page: https://builder.blender.org/download/